# "android:gravity" for custom button is not applying when defined in styles.xml

Tags: android, android-button, android-styles, android-gravity

I just can't center (vertically and horizontally) text in a Button I defined in styles.xml (works properly when all attributes are in layout)

Originally all attributes were set directly in the layout, but I have lots of fragments where all buttons are the same. When Button is fully declared in the layout I don't even need to specify a "gravity" value, text is automaticaly centered.

I tried to create a style for some attributes but I lost text centering and "android:gravity="center"" does not work, in the style and/or in the layout

**styles.xml**

```
<!-- GENERAL - BUTTON -->
    <style name="Widget.AppCompat.Button.one_line">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">50dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingStart">20dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingEnd">20dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">20dp</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/roboto_condensed_bold</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/default_text_size</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
    </style>
```

**myLayout.xml**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
...
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_back"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.one_line"
        android:background="@drawable/border_green_full"
        android:text="@string/retour"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: retour.png]

I would expect the text vertically centered. What am I missing ?

Comment: Remove `paddingBottom`

Comment: Why are you not inheriting from a parent style (ex. `Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button` )? the default has `<item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|center_horizontal</item>`

Comment: @GiddyNaya ... That is it. I wanted to set margin not padding. I'm dumb

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I am inheriting from "Widget.AppCompat.Button" through implicit inheritance

Comment: @Gilles true, my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case just remove the:

```
<item name="android:paddingBottom">20dp</item>
```

Better use a **parent** style:

```
<style name="Widget.AppCompat.Button.one_line" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button">
 ...
</style>
```

The default value in this case is:

```
<item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|center_horizontal</item>
```

In general:

> Originally all attributes were set directly in the layout, but I have lots of fragments where all buttons are the same

If you would like to **centralize the style for all the buttons** in your app, **avoiding** to specify the `style` attribute in any buttons in the layouts just use:

- with a **Material Theme** the **`materialButtonStyle`** attribute in your app theme:

Something like:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
     ...
    <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button</item>
  </style>
```

- with an **AppCompat theme** use the **`buttonStyle`** attribute:

Something like:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button</item>
</style>
```

If you would like to customize the style, define the **`parent`** style with `Widget.MaterialComponents.Button`/`Widget.AppCompat.Button`.

Comment: Thanks for the further explanation I'll keep that in mind. Thing is, I have some different button type so I don't want to set this style for all the app buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake like @GiddyNaya said, obviously add padding_bottom puts the text up in the button (I wanted to add margin, not padding...)